# Duplicity "add-only" incremental backup

Tags: backup, incremental-backup, duplicity

I have a large duplicity backup stored in a server that would be too slow and costly to fully restore, but I want to perform an incremental backup of a relatively small amount of data that was missing from the initial backup. I already have the signatures and manifests synchronized.

If I perform an incremental backup on a directory containing only the new files, then duplicity will mark the other files as deleted in the current version of the backup, but that's not what I want.

Is it possible to tell duplicity to ignore missing files and only add the new ones?